# iText pdf signature verification in android

Tags: android, itext, digital-signature

Sign PDf using iText, but signature verification is giving exception. Kindly help me in resolving the issue. 
What are the versions of itext , spongy castle libraryto be used?

currently I am using

1.sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar

2.scpkix-jdk15on-1.47.0.0.jar

3.scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.0.jar

4.itextg-5.4.5.jar

6.itext-2.1.7.jar

Exception is:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   **org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertParser 01-30 13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):    at
>   com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7.(Unknown** Source) 01-30
>   13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):     at
>   com.lowagie.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(Unknown Source) 01-30
>   13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):     at
>   com.lowagie.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(Unknown Source) 01-30
>   13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):     at
>   com.example.itextpdfsign.MainActivity.verifySignature(MainActivity.java:178)
>   01-30 13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):   at
>   com.example.itextpdfsign.MainActivity.verifySignatures(MainActivity.java:165)
>   01-30 13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):   at
>   com.example.itextpdfsign.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
>   01-30 13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   01-30 13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
>   01-30 13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>   01-30 13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 01-30
>   13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>   01-30 13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-30
>   13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 01-30 13:45:36.569:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8059):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 01-30
>   13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-30
>   13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 01-30 13:45:36.569:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8059):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   01-30 13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 01-30
>   13:45:36.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8059):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things that are wrong in your stacktrace:

1. I see a reference to my name: `com.lowagie` indicates that you're using an old iText version. This version should no longer be used for [specific reasons](http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq).
2. I see a reference to `org.bouncycastle`. This indicates that you're not using the Android port of iText.

You only need [iTextG](http://www.itextpdf.com/product/itextg). Don't use the `com.lowagie` stuff. Don't introduce a different version of BouncyCastle; use SpongyCastle instead.

Comment: @Bruno... thanks for clarifying my doubt. The exception i am getting only when i execute signature verification code i.e

Comment: public static PdfPKCS7 verifySignature(AcroFields fields, String name)
   throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
  System.out.println("Signature covers whole document: "
    + fields.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
  System.out.println("Document revision: " + fields.getRevision(name)
    + " of " + fields.getTotalRevisions());
  PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(name);
  System.out.println("Integrity check OK? " + pkcs7.verify());
  return pkcs7;
 }

Comment: here to refer PdfPKCS7 & AcroFields   iText-2.1.7jar  is required here i am getting error... kindly let me know for android is there any other version...

Comment: i checked the jar- iTextG where the package com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security LtvVerification- has reference to PdfPKCS7 & AcroFields  means iTextG for android also need these classes kindly let me know which jar includes these classes

Comment: AcroFields is part of iTextG: http://sourceforge.net/p/itextg/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ and so is PdfPKCS7: http://sourceforge.net/p/itextg/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/security/ so you'll have to be more specific when you say that you need another jar.